# Ember bound block helper

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm wondering if the registerBoundHelper in ember was ever meant to be able to handle the block style helpers. For example, I created the following:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('unlessUndefined', (context, options) ->
  unless typeof context == "undefined"
    return options.fn(this)
  else
    return options.inverse(this)
)
```

The idea being to use it as such:

```
{{#unlessUndefined choice}}
  {{#if choice}}
    <p>You chose yes</p>
  {{else}}
    <p>You chose no</p>
  {{/if}}
{{else}}
  <p>Make a choice</p>
{{/unlessUndefined}}
```

The option.fn(this) parts of things don't appear to render any output. When doing this I get an error in the console that says: "You can't use appendChild outside of the rendering process"

If this isn't possible, perhaps somebody can suggest another way to achieve a conditional block that will only show if the bound value isn't undefined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just spent a bunch of time fighting this and found a fix of sorts. I looked at the pull request with the implementation of the registerBoundHelper method.

I added the following above this line:
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/1274/files#L0R357

```
Ember.run.scheduleOnce('render', view, 'rerender')
```

It looks like the boundHelper method just wraps the original helper method and creates an anonymous view. The only problem is that the observer puts the anonymous view into render mode without putting the original view into the same first.

At least that's what I think is going on. Anyway, it works for me now. Maybe this is a bug?

Comment: Hi Paul. Thanks for posting this info. I am running the master version of Ember at the moment so I wasn't able to put your solution into practice. However I think you are right about the original view not being rerendered. 

With the changes they have made, it's not as easy as adding the line you mention as they do the rerender within a function and the context of that function doesn't have access to the original view. 

It's probably worth opening a bug on this once I can narrow down the behaviour.